# Does m2eclipse need EGit for git support

Tags: eclipse, git, m2eclipse, egit

Does m2eclipse use EGit for git support or does it just use the native git client installed on a machine?

I have both installed (plus the m2eclipse SCM integration plugin) and I was wondering if I still need EGit if I use m2eclipse's git support.

Answer (score 2):

If you have installed Maven SCM feature, you should be able to checkout projects from Git using [Maven SCM provider for Git](http://maven.apache.org/scm/git.html). This should work for "Checkout projects from SCM" wizard, assuming you know a correct project url to checkout.

Answer (score 0):

m2eclipse has no idea of git, so it needs a plugin which supports git (currently only EGit).

Inside the POM, the situation is different: Here, the Maven plugin (and not the one from Eclipse) is loaded. This SCM maven plugin uses the command line interface of the git client on the machine.